# python: загрузка библиотеки без использования import

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import

встретил такую задачу "загрузить модуль без использования import"

подскажите, как это вообще можно сделать, зная название модуля

знаю 3 способа

```
import math

from math import sqrt

__import__('math').sqrt
```

но везде используется `import`

а какие еще способы есть?

Comment: importlib, exec

Comment: а без exec - его я просто не стал указывать, поскольку решение очевидно и сводится к уже написанным

Comment: виноват, скорректировал

Comment: Ну значит importlib остается, но его тоже нужно импортировать, так что совсем без импорта - никак.

Comment: есть вариант, если модуль встроенный (как `math`): `math = locals()['__loader__'].load_module('math')` и теперь можно делать всё то же, что и если бы написали `import math`. но вот для невстроенных модулей (`requests`, например) этот способ не работает

Comment: вот такая конструкция не проходит `locals()['__loader__'].load_module('math').sqrt(16)`

Comment: @Zhihar странно. у меня работает (https://imgur.com/a/pP6beKJ)

Comment: у меня вот это выдает `locals()['__loader__'].load_module('math').sqrt(16)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 546, in _check_name_wrapper
ImportError: loader for __main__ cannot handle math`

Comment: @Zhihar а что вам выдает `locals()['__loader__']`, может в этом причина.. (у меня `<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>`

Comment: `<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001DEB70F47C0>` - вот это

Comment: @Zhihar причин не знаю, и помочь в "расследовании" нарядли смогу. Но похоже (судя по названию класса), что в вашем случае должен работать импорт невстроеных модулей, а вот встроеные не будут импортироваться.

Comment: Я конечно не очень понимаю, зачем не использовать `import`.

Comment: такая задачка - не используя import, __import__, eval, exec загрузить модуль